# Google Cloud Vision OCR Returns "Bad Image Data" on Google Cloud Shell Localhost

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blobstore, google-cloud-vision, google-cloud-shell

**tl;dr:** How can I get Google Cloud Vision OCR to work on Cloud Shell editor's localhost?

I'm using [Google Cloud Shell editor](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/viewing-and-editing-files), which contains a [web preview](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/using-web-preview) feature that serves "local" webservers at URLs like `https://8080-dot-10727374-dot-devshell.appspot.com/index.html`.

I'm following [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr) for Cloud Vision OCR. I put that example code into a servlet that uses Blobstore as an image host:

```java
package com.google.servlets;

import com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobInfo;
import com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobInfoFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobKey;
import com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreService;
import com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreServiceFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.images.ImagesService;
import com.google.appengine.api.images.ImagesServiceFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.images.ServingUrlOptions;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.AnnotateImageRequest;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.AnnotateImageResponse;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.BatchAnnotateImagesResponse;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.Feature;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.Image;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.ImageAnnotatorClient;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.ImageSource;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.TextAnnotation;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * When the user submits the form, Blobstore processes the file upload and then forwards the request
 * to this servlet. This servlet can then analyze the image using the Vision API.
 */
@WebServlet("/image-analysis")
public class ImageAnalysisServlet extends HttpServlet {

  @Override
  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    // Get the BlobKey that points to the image uploaded by the user.
    BlobKey blobKey = getBlobKey(request, "image");

    // Get the URL of the image that the user uploaded.
    String imageUrl = getUploadedFileUrl(blobKey);

   // Extract text from the image
    String text = detectDocumentText(imageUrl);

    // Output some HTML.
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    out.println("<p>Here's the image you uploaded:</p>");
    out.println("<a href=\"" + imageUrl + "\">");
    out.println("<img src=\"" + imageUrl + "\" />");
    out.println("</a>");
    out.println("<h1>text: " + text + "</h1>");
  }

    /**
   * Returns the BlobKey that points to the file uploaded by the user, or null if the user didn't
   * upload a file.
   */
  private BlobKey getBlobKey(HttpServletRequest request, String formInputElementName) {
    BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
    Map<String, List<BlobKey>> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploads(request);
    List<BlobKey> blobKeys = blobs.get("image");

    // User submitted form without selecting a file, so we can't get a BlobKey. (dev server)
    if (blobKeys == null || blobKeys.isEmpty()) {
      return null;
    }

    // Our form only contains a single file input, so get the first index.
    BlobKey blobKey = blobKeys.get(0);

    // User submitted form without selecting a file, so the BlobKey is empty. (live server)
    BlobInfo blobInfo = new BlobInfoFactory().loadBlobInfo(blobKey);
    if (blobInfo.getSize() == 0) {
      blobstoreService.delete(blobKey);
      return null;
    }

    return blobKey;
  }

  /** Returns a URL that points to the uploaded file. */
  private String getUploadedFileUrl(BlobKey blobKey) {
    ImagesService imagesService = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();
    ServingUrlOptions options = ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withBlobKey(blobKey);
    String url = imagesService.getServingUrl(options);

    // GCS's localhost preview is not actually on localhost,
    // so make the URL relative to the current domain.
    if(url.startsWith("http://localhost:8080/")){
      url = url.replace("http://localhost:8080/", "https://8080-dot-10727374-dot-devshell.appspot.com/");
    }

    return url;
  }

  private String detectDocumentText(String path) throws IOException {
    List<AnnotateImageRequest> requests = new ArrayList<>();
    ImageSource imgSource = ImageSource.newBuilder().setImageUri(path).build(); 
    Image img = Image.newBuilder().setSource(imgSource).build();
    Feature feat = Feature.newBuilder().setType(Feature.Type.DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION).build();
    AnnotateImageRequest request = AnnotateImageRequest.newBuilder().addFeatures(feat).setImage(img).build();
    requests.add(request);

    // Initialize client that will be used to send requests. This client only needs to be created
    // once, and can be reused for multiple requests. After completing all of your requests, call
    // the "close" method on the client to safely clean up any remaining background resources.
    try (ImageAnnotatorClient client = ImageAnnotatorClient.create()) {
      BatchAnnotateImagesResponse response = client.batchAnnotateImages(requests);
      List<AnnotateImageResponse> responses = response.getResponsesList();
      client.close();
      
      // Check to see if any of the responses are errors
      for (AnnotateImageResponse res : responses) {
        if (res.hasError()) {
          System.out.format("Error: %s%n", res.getError().getMessage());
          return "Error: " + res.getError().getMessage();
        }
    
        // For full list of available annotations, see http://g.co/cloud/vision/docs
        TextAnnotation annotation = res.getFullTextAnnotation();
        return annotation.getText();
      }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
      return "ERROR: ImageAnnotatorClient Failed, " + e;
    }
    // Case where the ImageAnnotatorClient works, but there are no responses from it.
    return "Error: No responses";
  }
}
```

When I deploy to a **real** server using the `mvn package appengine:deploy` command, this works perfectly:

[image: live server]

(Well, as perfectly as can be expected from this test image.)

However, if I deploy to a "local" devserver using the `mvn package appengine:run` command, then Google Cloud Vision returns a generic "Bad image data" error:

[image: devserver]

I'm guessing this is because the image URL (`https://8080-dot-10727374-dot-devshell.appspot.com/_cloudshellProxy/_ah/img/TjxgeYiHlCkix-XRj94jnw`) is not publicly accessible, because it's running on a "fake" localhost that requires me to be logged into my Google account to see.

How can I get Google Cloud Vision OCR to work on Cloud Shell editor's "fake" localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud Vision also supports reading image bytes directly rather than going through a URL. Switching to that allowed me to bypass the requirement to have a publicly accessible URL.

The line that matters is this one:

```
Image img = Image.newBuilder().setContent(ByteString.copyFrom(bytes)).build();
```

...where `bytes` come from what's stored in Blobstore.

Full code for reference:

```
package com.google.servlets;

import com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobInfo;
import com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobInfoFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobKey;
import com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreService;
import com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreServiceFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.images.ImagesService;
import com.google.appengine.api.images.ImagesServiceFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.images.ServingUrlOptions;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.AnnotateImageRequest;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.AnnotateImageResponse;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.BatchAnnotateImagesResponse;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.Feature;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.Image;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.ImageAnnotatorClient;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.ImageSource;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.TextAnnotation;
import com.google.protobuf.ByteString;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * When the user submits the form, Blobstore processes the file upload and then forwards the request
 * to this servlet. This servlet can then analyze the image using the Vision API.
 */
@WebServlet("/image-analysis")
public class ImageAnalysisServlet extends HttpServlet {

  @Override
  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    // Get the BlobKey that points to the image uploaded by the user.
    BlobKey blobKey = getBlobKey(request, "image");

    // Get the URL of the image that the user uploaded.
    String imageUrl = getUploadedFileUrl(blobKey);


    byte[] blobBytes = getBlobBytes(blobKey);

   // Extract text from the image
    String text = detectDocumentText(blobBytes);

    // Output some HTML.
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    out.println("<p>Here's the image you uploaded:</p>");
    out.println("<a href=\"" + imageUrl + "\">");
    out.println("<img src=\"" + imageUrl + "\" />");
    out.println("</a>");
    out.println("<h1>text: " + text + "</h1>");
  }

  private byte[] getBlobBytes(BlobKey blobKey) throws IOException {
    BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputBytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    int fetchSize = BlobstoreService.MAX_BLOB_FETCH_SIZE;
    long currentByteIndex = 0;
    boolean continueReading = true;
    while (continueReading) {
      // end index is inclusive, so we have to subtract 1 to get fetchSize bytes
      byte[] b =
          blobstoreService.fetchData(blobKey, currentByteIndex, currentByteIndex + fetchSize - 1);
      outputBytes.write(b);

      // if we read fewer bytes than we requested, then we reached the end
      if (b.length < fetchSize) {
        continueReading = false;
      }

      currentByteIndex += fetchSize;
    }

    return outputBytes.toByteArray();
  }

    /**
   * Returns the BlobKey that points to the file uploaded by the user, or null if the user didn't
   * upload a file.
   */
  private BlobKey getBlobKey(HttpServletRequest request, String formInputElementName) {
    BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
    Map<String, List<BlobKey>> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploads(request);
    List<BlobKey> blobKeys = blobs.get("image");

    // User submitted form without selecting a file, so we can't get a BlobKey. (dev server)
    if (blobKeys == null || blobKeys.isEmpty()) {
      return null;
    }

    // Our form only contains a single file input, so get the first index.
    BlobKey blobKey = blobKeys.get(0);

    // User submitted form without selecting a file, so the BlobKey is empty. (live server)
    BlobInfo blobInfo = new BlobInfoFactory().loadBlobInfo(blobKey);
    if (blobInfo.getSize() == 0) {
      blobstoreService.delete(blobKey);
      return null;
    }

    return blobKey;
  }

  /** Returns a URL that points to the uploaded file. */
  private String getUploadedFileUrl(BlobKey blobKey) {
    ImagesService imagesService = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();
    ServingUrlOptions options = ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withBlobKey(blobKey);
    String url = imagesService.getServingUrl(options);

    // GCS's localhost preview is not actually on localhost,
    // so make the URL relative to the current domain.
    if(url.startsWith("http://localhost:8080/")){
      url = url.replace("http://localhost:8080/", "https://8080-dot-10727374-dot-devshell.appspot.com/");
    }

    return url;
  }

  private String detectDocumentText(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
    List<AnnotateImageRequest> requests = new ArrayList<>();
    Image img = Image.newBuilder().setContent(ByteString.copyFrom(bytes)).build();
    Feature feat = Feature.newBuilder().setType(Feature.Type.DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION).build();
    AnnotateImageRequest request = AnnotateImageRequest.newBuilder().addFeatures(feat).setImage(img).build();
    requests.add(request);

    // Initialize client that will be used to send requests. This client only needs to be created
    // once, and can be reused for multiple requests. After completing all of your requests, call
    // the "close" method on the client to safely clean up any remaining background resources.
    try (ImageAnnotatorClient client = ImageAnnotatorClient.create()) {
      BatchAnnotateImagesResponse response = client.batchAnnotateImages(requests);
      List<AnnotateImageResponse> responses = response.getResponsesList();
      client.close();
      
      // Check to see if any of the responses are errors
      for (AnnotateImageResponse res : responses) {
        if (res.hasError()) {
          System.out.format("Error: %s%n", res.getError().getMessage());
          return "Error: " + res.getError().getMessage();
        }
    
        // For full list of available annotations, see http://g.co/cloud/vision/docs
        TextAnnotation annotation = res.getFullTextAnnotation();
        return annotation.getText();
      }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
      return "ERROR: ImageAnnotatorClient Failed, " + e;
    }
    // Case where the ImageAnnotatorClient works, but there are no responses from it.
    return "Error: No responses";
  }
}
```